# I implemented this merge sort algorithm into java and it didn't work

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, mergesort

This my introductory course to Algorithms, and I understand algorithms and I can design them, but this is the first time I tryed to apply it in java code, please tell me what i did wrong in this code for it to not work properly
[I'm trying to apply this algorithm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmvO8.png) ,
[this is the rest of the algorithm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOe8r.png)

This is my main void:

```
int[] A = { 5, 2, 4, 7, 1, 3, 2, 6 };
int p = 1;
int r = A.length;

Main obi = new Main ();
obi.mergeSort (A, p, r);
```

my first function:

```java
public void mergeSort (int[]A, int p, int r) {

    if (p < r){
        int q = (p + r) / 2;
        mergeSort (A, p, q);
        mergeSort (A, q + 1, r);
        merge (A, p, q, r);
    }

}
```

my second function:

```java
public void merge (int[]A, int p, int q, int r) {

    int n1 = q - p + 1;
    int n2 = r - q;

    int L[] = new int[n1];
    int R[] = new int[n2];

    for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++){
        L[i] = A[p + i - 1];
        
    }
    
    for (int j = 0; j < n2; j++){
        R[j] = A[q + j];
        
    }
    
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    for (int k = p - 1; k < r; k++){
        if (L[i] <= R[j]){
            A[k] = L[i];
            i = i + 1;
            
        } else {
            A[k] = R[j];
            j = j + 1;
            
        }
    }

}
```

And this is the error message I got:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at Main.merge(Main.java:44)
    at Main.mergeSort(Main.java:19)
    at Main.mergeSort(Main.java:17)
    at Main.mergeSort(Main.java:17)
    at Main.main(Main.java:10)
```

I tried to let L[] and R[] have length n1+1 and n2+1 but it didn't help.

Comment: Could you mark the lines that gives the errors.

Comment: @Surt It is the `if (L[i] <= R[j]){` line.

Comment: The pseudo-code in the two images use arrays that are **1-based**. Java arrays are **0-based**, so you need to adjust all the code to reflect that. Trying to fix the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` specifically is the wrong approach. You need to correct apply the pseudo-code to Java, so delete this question for now, do the coding again, appropriately adjusting for the difference in 1-based and 0-based arrays. Hopefully the new code will work. If not, *debug* your own code before asking for help again.

Comment: Line 10 is: obi.mergeSort (A, p, r); Line 17 is: mergeSort (A, p, q); Line 19 is: merge (A, p, q, r); Line 44 is: if (L[i] <= R[j]){

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- the arguments `r` and `q` should be the index of the first element in the slice, hence `int p = 0;` in `main()` instead of `1`, and the index past the last element in the slice, hence correctly `int r = A.length;`

With this convention, there is no need for confusing and error prone `+1`/`-1` adjustments in the `merge` and `mergeSort` methods.

Furthermore, the merging loop in `merge` should be modified to avoid accessing `L[i]` or `R[j]` when the corresponding index reaches the length of the array.

Here is a modified version:

```
    ...
    int[] A = { 5, 2, 4, 7, 1, 3, 2, 6 };
    int p = 0;
    int r = A.length;

    Main obi = new Main();
    obi.mergeSort(A, p, r);
    ...

public void mergeSort(int[]A, int p, int r) {
    if (r - p > 1) {
        int q = p + (r - p) / 2;
        mergeSort(A, p, q);
        mergeSort(A, q, r);
        merge(A, p, q, r);
    }
}

public void merge(int[]A, int p, int q, int r) {
    int n1 = q - p;
    int n2 = r - q;

    int L[] = new int[n1];
    int R[] = new int[n2];

    for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++) {
        L[i] = A[p + i];
    }
    
    for (int j = 0; j < n2; j++) {
        R[j] = A[q + j];
    }
    
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    for (int k = p; k < r; k++) {
        if (i < n1 && (j >= n2 || L[i] <= R[j])) {
            A[k] = L[i];
            i = i + 1;
        } else {
            A[k] = R[j];
            j = j + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the `merge` method can be simplified as the elements of the second half never get overwritten before they are moved into their final spot, so there is no need to save them:

```
public void merge(int[]A, int p, int q, int r) {
    int n1 = q - p;
    int L[] = new int[n1];
    for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++) {
        L[i] = A[p + i];
    }
    
    int i = 0;
    int j = q;
    int k = p;

    while (i < n1) {
        if (j >= r || L[i] <= A[j])
            A[k++] = L[i++];
        else
            A[k++] = A[j++];
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Either `L` or `R` finishes first.

```
for (int k = p - 1; k < r; k++){
    if (L[i] <= R[j]){
        A[k] = L[i];
        i = i + 1;   
    } else {
        A[k] = R[j];
        j = j + 1;   
    }
}
```

Lets say L finishes first then i becomes L.length+1 so that when the next iteration occurs `L[i]` is invalid as its one past the end.